# Remove permantly black areas of a raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, merge

In order to combine these two DEMs in a right way, I need to remove their black part permanently:

[image]

Seeing similar problems here, a proposed solution is adjusting the transparency to 0. In this way, although before performing the merge I see it well, the result is not good (black appears again):

[image]

[image]

How can I do it? The black areas have a value of zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant remove them, a raster has to be rectangular, but you can use Warp (reproject) to set nodata value to zero which will make them transparent:

[image]